# Black webview onResume

Tags: android, view, webview, onresume, onpause

I'm having a WebView in my app, and I want it running forever.

When I return to my app **(onResume), the WebView is a black screen...**

I tried multiple solutions, and Layouts. I am adding the WebView with the function *setContentView(w);*

On the first run it works fine. When I push the home button the WebView is still running (console.log(), from the javascript give feedback). Comming back to the app, I see a black screen. The WebView is still running, but I cant see it :(.

I've tried also to add it to an .xml View file, but without result. I want also to prevent the page from reloading. I tried to set the View visible. Tried some functions as w.invalidate().

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_FROM_NOTIFICATION = "EXTRA_FROM_NOTIFICATION";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("main"," create ");
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestService.class);
            TestService.setMain(this);
            TestService.setView();
            MainActivity.this.startService(i);
        } else {
            TestService.setAgain(); 
        }
     }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.v("main","back press");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**TestService.java**

```
public class TestService extends Service {
    private static WebView w;
    private static MainActivity ma;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {       
            super.onCreate();
    }
    public static void setMain(MainActivity a) {
        ma = a;
        Log.e("main", " setData " );
    }

    public static void setView() {
        Log.e("TestService", "FIRST TIME SETUP");
        w = new WebView(ma);
        ma.setContentView(w);
        w.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); // use localstorage
        w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    }

    public static void setAgain() {
        w.bringToFront();
        w.loadUrl("javascript: test();");
        Log.e("TestService", w.getVisibility() + "");   // returns 0 (View.VISIBLE)
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Webview test Android</title>
<style>
body {
  background: white;
}
html {
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
   Counter<br>
  <h1><div id="counter"></div></h1>
  <script>
   var counter = 0;
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
   setTimeout(function(){ count(); }, 1000);

   function test() {
      console.log("Test");
      alert("Jooo");
   }


   function count() {
      counter++;
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
      setTimeout(function(){ count(); }, 1000);
      console.log("count " + counter);
   } 
</script>
  <font color="#ff0">Test</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Maybe anyone knows the right way to go?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Service is explicitly meant for processing data in background.
Displaying anything from a service is not allowed (except for a few special cases), nor recommended.

In your case i can see you're doing

```
setContentView(...);
```

only once. Try to re-attach it in the

```
else {
    TestService.setAgain(); 
}
```

condition, because that is why you're getting black screen.

However, still I can see a very bad design here. I think I could help, if you could precisely state what you're trying to achieve - ie. what is the purpose for your workflow.

I guess it may be related to some kind of javascript running in the background? Generally this is a bad practice. User will expect the application to stop consuming resources one home is pressed or app is taken off the foreground. Of course, unless you're writing javascript based bitcoin miner :)

Comment: Yeah. I think my Android skills are not so good... What I want to do is keep a NodeJs site open. An example what I'm trying to do is a sort of Gps tracking. I want to give feedback to the app when someone needs this user. Then I can give a Toast to the user.

Comment: If you're trying to access native features from a web enviroment, try http://cordova.apache.org/ 
Also it should be rather done as a REST based calls located in a background service, rather than the whole webview.
Chances are, the platform will kill your service pretty fast, given the load it will generate. Also no 100% guarantees this service will live on after the app is killed.

Try to make a simple HTTP GET to a REST api rather than using javascript. This way you can run small parts of data from the background.

Comment: Ok. I understand it is a bad way. So maybe its better than to reload the whole page. And get some data from the native app.